# Calculate number of characters in string in R

Tags: r, text, data-manipulation

My sample dataset looks like below. I need to calculate the number of characters.

```
keyword <- c("advertising",
         "advertising budget",
         "marketing plan detail",
         "marketing budget and forecast")
```

I tried the "nchar" function, but it actually calculates the number of digits. For this sample, the results should be 1,2,3,4.

Comment: Perhaps you want to count the number of words, not the number of characters. In any event -- `nchar` doesn't count the number of digits. Your example contains no digits.

Comment: `stringi::stri_count_words(keyword)`

Answer (score 2):

One option is `str_count` and specify the patterns for word (`\\w+`)

```
library(stringr)
str_count(keyword, "\\w+")
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
lengths(gregexpr("\\w+", keyword))
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
unlist( lapply(strsplit(keyword, split = "\ "), length) )
[1] 1 2 3 4
```